# How to Instantiate an Anylogic block/Object (INode)

Tags: java, simulation, instantiation, anylogic

I have set up different product types that go through processes and end up in a Warehouse. Now i want to decide where to put it using say a moveTo block. So i need to get an INode (a rectangular node) for the product. So i want to write a function that takes the product type (its an Option List type) and returns the INode my function looks like:
[See this image for function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVJQT.png)

The Code:

```html
INode location = new INode();
switch(product){
 case GREEN: location = sortGreen; break;
 case RED: location = sortRed; break;
 case BLUE: location = sortBlue; break;
 case MAGENTA: location = sortMagenta; break;
 case YELLOW: location = sortYellow; break;
 }
return location;
```

This generates an error:

```
 "Cannot Instantiate type INode"
```

The manual doesnt have much about using blocks and Anylogic Objects in code. Can anyone assist in Instantiating this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick... No need to instantiate in the beginning.

```
switch(product){
    case GREEN: return sortGreen;
    case RED: return sortRed;
    case BLUE: return sortBlue;
    case MAGENTA: return sortMagenta;
    case YELLOW: return sortYellow;
}
return null;
```

Comment: Two dummies with the exact same thinking here :D

Comment: Thanks Felipe. This worked. I actually thought i tried this and was getting a mismatched error. But in the midst of trying many things i might have made an error.  So to get this clear, I can reference any object in the model by just name, I guess once the type is correct (In this case INode). Is there a handy list somewhere of all the common Objects types? Anylogic calls it "Rectangular Node" in the interface, I stumbled on INode by fluke as the name. The API reference is exhaustive and confusing. You can see how well this works here: [video](https://gofile.io/?c=fBAq2t). Thianks